# Use micromamba virtual environment in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-devcontainer, mamba

We have to use micromamba for our app because conda is prohibitively slow for installing our packages. We use a devcontainer to install micromamba and its packages. This works for the VS Code terminal but the editor still cannot find my packages.

I only see a way to activate the micromamba environment with a shell script snippet or shell rc file. The works for the terminal, but I dont see a way to activate it for the editor processes. The closest setting I found is specific to `venv`s.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this is to use the micromamba extension for VS Code.  It will allow you to activate existing Mamba environments or create new ones:
https://github.com/mamba-org/vscode-micromamba
To install it, go to the extensions tab in VS Code and search for Mamba.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add a `.env` file setting `PYTHONPATH` to the modules. Then setting `"python.envFile"` in .vscode/settings.json to point to that .env file.

Comment: Please could you kindly elaborate and cite some sources? I have the same problem.